# Object not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I am getting the error message

> Object not set to an instance of an object.

Now I understand that this error message means that I am calling a object that is holding the value of null, and I think I know where this is happening in my code, I just need to know how to fix it. Inside form1(`MainBox`)'s class I have made a reference to form2(`ApplicationProperties`). Inside form1, I am trying to write to a .xml file with the values from combo boxes on form2. This is where the error message is firing.

At

```
CreateNode(ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Portbx.SelectedItem.ToString(),.........

public partial class MainBox : Form
{
    //Making a refernce of Form2 called 'form2'.
    ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
       public void SaveApplicationProperties()
    {
        try
        {
            //CreateNode(everything being referenced. Put text boxes, and drop down boxes here.
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\ForteSenderv3.0\Properties.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            //Making the code indeted by 2 characters.
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;
            //Making the start element "Table".
            writer.WriteStartElement("Forte_Data_Gatherer_Application");
            //Calling the rst of the .xml file to write.
            CreateNode(ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Portbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), ApplicationPropertiesWindow.BaudRatebx.SelectedItem.ToString(), ApplicationPropertiesWindow.DataBitsbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Paritybx.SelectedItem.ToString(), ApplicationPropertiesWindow.StopBitsbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Handshakingbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Writing to .xml file failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }//End SaveApplicationProperties().

  }
```

In form2(`ApplicationProperties`), I am clicking a button, which should write to the .xml file.

```
    private void CommPortAcceptbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Making an instance of MainBox.
        var MainBoxWindow = new MainBox();
        //Need to set text boxes to change the values of the comm port.
        //PropertiesHaveChanged();
        MainBoxWindow.SaveApplicationProperties();
        //Hiding the window, because closing it makes the window unaccessible.
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
    }
```

At the top of the event handler, I am making a new instance of the first form, so I can call back to the `CreateNode` funciton in form1.

So I believe that it is the way I am going about referencing and making instances between the forms that is giving me a null value. I was wondering what I can do to fix this and carry the value over to the other form, and be able to write it to the .xml file.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I would suggest not having one form calling another's methods like this... raise an event and pass a com port configuration struct instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `SelectedItem` is null. Set the breakpoint on that line and inspect the `SelectedItem` property to see if it is null.

As an aside, the pattern you are using to do this is not a recommended pattern. You should pass information between forms via events, callbacks, return values, etc; rather than reaching into one form from another.

**Edit per comment #1**

Bear in mind that I don't have your actual code, so this is a *very* rough example...

```
public partial class ApplicationProperties : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SaveRequested;

    public SomeObjectType Portbx        {get;set;}
    public SomeObjectType BaudRatebx    {get;set;}
    public SomeObjectType DataBitsbx    {get;set;}
    public SomeObjectType Paritybx      {get;set;}
    public SomeObjectType StopBitsbx    {get;set;}
    public SomeObjectType Handshakingbx { get; set; }

    public ApplicationProperties()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommPortAcceptbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveRequested != null)
            SaveRequested(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public partial class MainBox : Form
{
    ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow;
    public MainBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
        ApplicationPropertiesWindow.SaveRequested += ApplicationPropertiesWindow_SaveRequested;
    }

    void ApplicationPropertiesWindow_SaveRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Hide();
        SaveApplicationProperties();
    }

    public void SaveApplicationProperties()
    {

        try
        {
            //CreateNode(everything being referenced. Put text boxes, and drop down boxes here.
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\ForteSenderv3.0\Properties.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            //Making the code indeted by 2 characters.
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;
            //Making the start element "Table".
            writer.WriteStartElement("Forte_Data_Gatherer_Application");
            //Calling the rst of the .xml file to write.
            CreateNode(
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Portbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.BaudRatebx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.DataBitsbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Paritybx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.StopBitsbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                ApplicationPropertiesWindow.Handshakingbx.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Writing to .xml file failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now there's no circular references. The parent form holds a reference to it's child, but the child knows nothing of the parent.

The parent is notified of the child's activity through an event. Normally I would wrap all the data necessary to respond to the event into the EventArgs; but, in this case, there's a lot of data, and I don't know what exactly it is.

The parent responds to the child's activity by querying the child for it's state via usage of properties.

Comment: SelectedItem is null, I was just wondering how I would be able to make the forms co-operate how I have them set up now.